В каких случаях нужно обязательно указывать тип данных для литералов в Postgres?
После миграции из Oracle в PostgreSQL подрядчиком запросов и представлений имею на руках вот такой код (пример):
         AND (lm.lmurre ~~ '%PFE%'::TEXT OR lm.lmurre ~~ '%OTC%'::TEXT)
         AND lm.lmurre !~~ '%Tenor%'::TEXT
         AND lm.lmurre !~~ '%TN_LMT%'::TEXT
         AND lm.lmurre !~~ '%SR%'::TEXT
         AND xbu.rienshna <> 'RBB'::TEXT
         AND xbu.rienshna !~~ '%ARO%'::TEXT

Насколько я понимаю, текстовые литералы по умолчанию и так являют собой тип данных TEXT.
Вопрос: зачем нужно указывать тип данных литерала (в том числе чиловых), если он по умолчанию и так интерпретируется как тот же тип данных? Есть ли в Postgres случаи, когда это становится критичным?

Подозреваю, что они руками мало где правили скрипты, скорее всего отработал какой-то "мигрирующий" скрипт. Куча косяков повылезала -.- Поэтому я ускореено изучаю разницу в субд и возник вот такой вопрос. Потому что местами в коде выглядит это довольно перегруженно и даже уродливо и хочется убрать лишнее.

Если указать, хуже не будет. Если не указать, то можно и нарваться. Не в показанных случаях, конечно, но вообще ошибки типа "мы не нашли функцию с указанными типами аргументов" - не экзотика.

@Akina ну вот я умом то понимаю, что нарваться можно, поэтому хочется узнать где именно =) А вы в постгресе работаете в повседневности? Типы каждый раз указываете?

вы в постгресе работаете в повседневности? Нет. Эпизодически, весьма. Типы каждый раз указываете? Я - только наткнувшись на проблему несовпадения типов. Но я как раз не показатель.

Все литералы изначально рассматриваются как unknown тип, дальше работают правила Operator Type Resolution. Вот в конце этих правил уже действительно есть приоритет считать unknown за text, но только таким образом если останется лишь один подходящий.

a) Discard candidate operators for which the input types do not match and cannot be converted (using an implicit conversion) to match.
unknown literals are assumed to be convertible to anything for this
purpose. If only one candidate remains, use it; else continue to the
next step.
b) If any input argument is of a domain type, treat it as being of the domain's base type for all subsequent steps. This ensures that
domains act like their base types for purposes of ambiguous-operator
resolution.
c)    Run through all candidates and keep those with the most exact matches on input types. Keep all candidates if none have exact
matches. If only one candidate remains, use it; else continue to the
next step.
e)    Run through all candidates and keep those that accept preferred types (of the input data type's type category) at the most positions
where type conversion will be required. Keep all candidates if none
accept preferred types. If only one candidate remains, use it; else
continue to the next step.
d)    If any input arguments are unknown, check the type categories accepted at those argument positions by the remaining candidates. At
each position, select the string category if any candidate accepts
that category. (This bias towards string is appropriate since an
unknown-type literal looks like a string.) Otherwise, if all the
remaining candidates accept the same type category, select that
category; otherwise fail because the correct choice cannot be deduced
without more clues. Now discard candidates that do not accept the
selected type category. Furthermore, if any candidate accepts a
preferred type in that category, discard candidates that accept
non-preferred types for that argument. Keep all candidates if none
survive these tests. If only one candidate remains, use it; else
continue to the next step.
f)    If there are both unknown and known-type arguments, and all the known-type arguments have the same type, assume that the unknown
arguments are also of that type, and check which candidates can accept
that type at the unknown-argument positions. If exactly one candidate
passes this test, use it. Otherwise, fail.

В большинстве случаев вы работаете с бинарными операторами, где тип одного из операндов известен базе заранее (используется поле таблицы, результат функции и подобные случаи). Основываясь на операторе и одном из операндов с известным типом подобрать тип второго операнда обычно возможно без проблем. Сложнее с унарными операторами:
melkij=> select ~ 123;
 ?column? 
----------
     -124
(1 row)

melkij=> select ~ '123';
ERROR:  operator is not unique: ~ unknown
LINE 1: select ~ '123';
               ^
HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate operator. You might need to add explicit type casts.

оп, и тут уже не понимаем, какой оператор использовать уместнее было бы. Потому что это может не числовой литерал, а, например, inet (который даже начинается с числа, но так далеко парсер лезть не будет с угадываем, не число ли это на самом деле).
Ну а полный список таких случаев невозможен, такова цена расширяемости postgresql: у вас могут быть собственные типы данных и собственные операторы, которые, соответственно, могут добавить новую альтернативу для определения типа.

Обычно тип не указывают без явной необходимости.
